# How to pass --device-cgroup-rule by docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to use `--device-cgroup-rule` option, it works fine with `docker run` command, but I want to use it also in my docker-compose.yml file. But I didn't find it in the documentation. Is it possible at least?

Answer (score 13):

documented here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#device_cgroup_rules

```
device_cgroup_rules:
  - 'c 1:3 mr'
  - 'a 7:* rmw'
```

it has been added quite recently it seems from the thread https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5622

Comment: It seems that Docker Compose file format version 3 lost this capability. There is a pull request to readd it in 3.7: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/6974

Comment: I see there are resync and commit - https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/6974/commits, how can I track which version released with the merge?